# Disabling the review queue icon badge

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, user-interface, top-bar

Can the review queue icon badge be disabled? It surely increases the engagement but it is very distracting during coding.

Comment: If you really don't like it being there, you could always write a user script to hide it, and just turn the script on/off when you do/don't want to see it. But we're not going to build an option like that into our system.

Comment: Why not? I will not use the feature, and I have no responsibility to your employer to use it. Can you remove moderator status on request (leaving my account otherwise active) so that this goes away? Btw, I wish you would not link to pro-police material from your staff account

Comment: If you are using ublock origin. just right-click, block element on the badge. Thats how I got rid of distracting badge

Answer (score 2):

One of our jobs as contributors to these sites is to keep an eye on the review queues. A specific function to attenuate the attention those queues require would be counter-productive to the operation of the sites.

On your specific issue of distraction, consider minimising your browser window when you are coding, or if you need the browser up, then you could always close the relevant Stack Exchange page.

That ought to help with your concentration.

Comment: Or use [a blank page](http://www.pmortensen.eu/empty.html)...

Comment: Why do I have an unpaid job? I have *no* job to serve this for-profit organization. I have no responsibility to monitor these queues. Nothing is required of me and I will completely ignore them

Answer (score 2):

What an absolutely horrible system to use! I have a lot of reputation on StackOverflow because I happened to ask a couple of good questions. I rarely use the site, don't know my way around it, and have no interest in learning it. But, I have moderation privileges that I don't understand and can't disable. Frankly, I'd rather use the site logged out than be "expected" to moderate things that I have no understanding of!

Comment: It is garbage unpaid labor that the for-profit site externalizes so that they can remain profitable without being responsible for content moderation